# xsd validation ERROR with both minOccurs and length used simultaneously

Tags: xsd

```
    <xsd:element name="CurrencyCode" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction>
        <xsd:length value="3"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>
```

I want my Currencycode to be an optional value and if at all there is a value it should have a length of 3 letters .. either my CurrencyCode can have Length=0 or length=3

When i use the above code the validator returns an error when there is an empty field 
[image: ERROR]

So how can i deal with this ??

Comment: Can you post example XML?  Are you trying to make the `CurrencyCode` *element* optional, or the *value* optional (e.g. have an empty element).  There is a difference.

Comment: <CurrencyCode></CurrencyCode> contents are optional not attributes ..

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040286/making-an-element-optional-using-xsd-cvc-length-valid-error by the same user. Currently both questions have accepted answers. In that question I also have an answer with three different ways to solve this problem. Should these be merged somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not tried this (do not have suitable env set up on this machine) but according to the specification you can do as follows:

```
<xsd:element name="CurrencyCode" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string">
   <xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
         <xsd:pattern value="(?:^$|\w{3})"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

Regular expression `(?:^$|\w{3})` matches either empty string or exactly three word characters. You can use `(?:^$|[A-Z]{3})` in case you want to accept currency codes only in upper case.

Comment: InvalidRegex: Pattern value '(?:^$|[A-Z]{3})' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 'This expression is not supported in the current option setting.' at column '3'.I got this ERROR :(

Comment: RegExp in XML Schema are implicitly anchored.

Comment: @Praneel: How about a simple `<xsd:pattern value="(\w{3})?"/>`